# set the default of a ExtentTest to FAILED

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-reporting

I am using [extentreports](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/) to add reports for my test which is written with Java and Selenium.
I notice that if a ExtentTest has two logs, "INFO" and "PASSED", if the pass log is not catched it will be considered as PASSED. How can I change it in a way that if a test is not passed it will automatically be singed as Failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible to change the behavior to fail the test case by default. Its a design decision, every test framework follows (TestNG, Junit, NUnit etc) not just Extent Reports.

The assumption is to start the test, that it will always pass. So even you have only Info logs, test case is marked as passed.

However, if by default, you assume the test is failed, until you encounter PASS, the test is still considered FAILED, because, even a single fail status in the entire test fails the test, regardless of how many pass logs you have.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide detail of your code and version you are using for extent report.
Assume u are using extent report version 2.40 and use this code :

```
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result)
{
    if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {
    //hope u know how to create ExtenTest and ExtentReport instance 
    //logger is extent test instance
    logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Title verification", image);


}

//report is ExtentReport instance
report.endTest(logger);
report.flush();

}
```

Comment: actually in my tests there are too many cases that a test may fail so I wanted to do it in this way that I put `logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Title verification", image);` at the end of each test and assume that if the test does not reach to this line of code it has failed.

Comment: Noor's response is correct. AfterMethod runs automatically after each test, no requirement to do anything manually.  Let the test framework decide the status and just report in AfterMethod.  What test framework do u use?